# how to stop a function in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this, I have written a function to "bookmark_outer" div and inside that div, there are 3 separate links and they also contain separate functions.when I click a link in that div, function in out div will also fire.How do I stop that?

```js
function bookmarkUrlRedirect{
    $('#Bookmark_title').closest('.bookmark_outer').find('.bookmark_edit').addClass('bkshow');
    }
    
function SaveBookmarkTitle{
    $('#bokmarksave').closest('.bookmark_outer').find('.bookmark_edit').addClass('bkshow');
    }
    
function EditBookmarkTitle{
    $('#bokmarksave').closest('.bookmark_outer').find('.bookmark_edit').addClass('bkshow');
    }
function DeleteBookmark{
    $('#bokmarksave').closest('.bookmark_outer').find('.bookmark_edit').addClass('bkshow');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bookmark_outer" onclick="bookmarkUrlRedirect">
  <div class="bookmark_txt">
    <h4 id="Bookmark_title" class="bookmark_id">Bookmark 1
    </h4>
    <p id="bookmark_Des" class="bookmark_cmt">URl testing
    </p>
    <p id="bookmark_page" class="page_num">Page 1 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bookmark_icon"> 
    <a href="#" class="bokmarksave" onclick="SaveBookmarkTitle">
      link1
    </a><br>
    <a onclick="EditBookmarkTitle" href="#">
      link2
    </a> <br>
    <a href="#" onclick="DeleteBookmark" class="Bkhide">
      link3 
    </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `event.stoppropagation()` in each function

Read this article https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

You will understand why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

To stop a function you can use **`return false`**.

To stop default action of a element use **`stopPropagation()`**. Like default event of a tag or submit button.

In your case, as you don't want to get div click fired when click on a. So, for this try placing the **`a`** outside **`div`** and display the **`a`** inside using position. I think this might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return` where you want to stop your function.